# Gfortran pre-processor directives for Different Operating systems

Tags: preprocessor, fortran

Could you tell me please how can I do the following:

```
#if __unix__
#define path_sep='/'
#elif __windows__
#define path_sep='\'
#else
#error "path_sep not defined."
#endif
```

using gfortran compiler.

Comment: gfortran's manual contains instructions on how to use the preprocessor. Is there anything about them that's not clear to you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done in combination with conditional compilation and using the "D" option on the command line.   Here is some example code:

```
program test_Dopt
character (len=1) :: pathsep
pathsep = "?"
#ifdef WOS
   pathsep = "\"
#endif
#ifdef UOS
   pathsep = "/"
#endif

write (*, '( "pathsep is >", A1, "<")' )  pathsep

end program test_Dopt
```

Name the program with filetype F90 to cause gfortran to run the preprocessor or use -cpp on the compile line.   Then pass options to the prepreprocessor by including them after D on the compile line, e.g., gfortran -DWOS.   (This is more general then gfortran -- most Fortran compilers will process C-style pre-processor directives.)  Then you can identify the OS outside of Fortran and pass the information to the Fortran program.

You can compile your code via using the filetype F90 or -cpp.

Comment: `__unix__` and `_WIN32` are the usual predefined preprocessor flags used to indicate which system you are on in most compilers.