# Generate list of preprocessor macros defined by the compiler

Tags: c, fortran, preprocessor, icc, intel-fortran

With gcc and gfortran I can generate a list of preprossesor macros defined by the compiler using (edited to reflect ouah's answer)

```
gcc -E -dM - < /dev/null
```

and

```
gfortran -cpp -E -dM /dev/null
```

respectively (on Linux at least).

How can I do the same with the Intel compilers icc and ifort? I know that for ifort these macros are defined [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/fortran/win/compiler_f/bldaps_for/common/bldaps_use_presym.htm), but I would like to be able to generate this list myself, since the exact macros in use and their values will depend on the compiler options used. I am also aware of the [predef](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Operating_Systems) project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Intel Fortran compiler, ifort, the following can be used:

```
ifort -E -fpp /dev/null -dryrun 2>&1 | grep -e -D | cut -c 5-
```

It seems than ifort does not have an equivalent `-dM` flag like icc, gfortran and gcc do.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer since I was really only concerned in getting the preprocessor directives used with ifort (generalisation to include the intel C compiler was just to hopefully make the question more generally useful).

Comment: `ifort` is always the trickier one -- so thanks for including it!

Answer (score 11):

Use this with the Intel compiler:

```
icc -E -dM - < /dev/null
```

Note that with `gcc`, the `-E` option is also required if you want to use the `-dM` preprocessor option.

Comment: Thanks for the note on using the `-E` option with `gcc` - I have edited my question to include this flag. Any ideas on doing the same with ifort?

Answer (score 1):

For `gfortran`, beware that `gfortran -E -dM - < /dev/null` yields the same result as if you had called `gcc`, which probably isn't helpful. You probably want something like this ([source](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Predefined+preprocessor+macros)):

`gfortran -cpp -E -dM empty.f`

That will give you a smaller list of what `gfortran` actually predefines. You will note that the results most likely do not include anything helpful for determining the operating system. Generally, for Fortran, you're left to define those yourself. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636470/289099) for additional detail. You could also try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23872966/289099), but I'm a little skeptical of the practically of that solution. Also, that link implies that at one time `gfortran` defined more than it does now.