# What is the macro testing AVX-2 arch for Intel CPU?

Tags: c++, c, macros, intel

Is there an icc macro that can test whether the CPU support AVX-2 or not?

`__AVX2__` doesnt work, btw.

Comment: You can dump all defined macros, see this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224334/gcc-dump-preprocessor-defines

Comment: Have you already written/tested your arch-specific code?  I would create my own `#define` macro and wrap my code in that, then use a make option or a top-level definitions file to create the real definition based on `#if` and `#ifdef` and other such code.

Comment: @abiessu yes, I usually use predefined arch-macro for that kind of stuff, however I cannot find the macro for AVX-2 arch.

Comment: @koodawg: Thats the macro for gcc/g++, I use icc (intel C/C++ compiler).

Comment: I understand that you are looking for a predefined macro, but I think a good practice would be to start by assuming that there isn't one and programming that way, then doing a detailed search through the ICC documentation for predefined macros.

Comment: `__AVX2__` works on every compiler I've tested so far (gcc, clang, icc) - what icc version are you using and what command line switches are you passing to it ?

Answer (score 3):

According to this thread

[Generate list of preprocessor macros defined by the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349754/generate-list-of-preprocessor-macros-defined-by-the-compiler)

the same -dM works for icc.