# Preprocessor Macro not working on Windows in Fortran Code

Tags: macros, fortran, gfortran

Dear All I have a small Fortran program containing preprocessor macro. Below is a minimal example. On mac os x, it works well but when I compile it on windows 7 (64-bit) it always prints `unknown operating system`. I am using gfortran-4.8.0 (mingw32) on windows 7.

```
      program foo
      implicit integer(i-n), double precision (a-h,o-p),
     + character*8(x-z)
*
#ifdef _WIN64
      zterm = 'wxt'
#elif _WIN32
      zterm = 'wxt'
#elif __APPLE__
      zterm = 'aqua'
#elif __linux
      zterm = 'x11'
#elif __unix
      zterm = 'x11'
#elif __posix
      zterm = 'x11'
#else
      print*, 'unknown operating system'
#endif
      end program foo
```

Changing `#ifdef _WIN64` to `#if defined (_WIN64)` did not help. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: On Mac I don't pass any flag to the compiler. Just normal `gfortran -o foo foo.F` and it works fine. So I did the same on windows, but there it does not work.

Comment: According to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.fortran/Xlyi2iRqlf8/TAWRSg2q378J the .F90 suffix should suffice. Also `_WIN64` should be OK. I don't use Windows however.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, Thanks, I tried `gfortran -cpp -o foo foo.F` but the problem is still there.

Comment: Do you have native compiler, or cygwin?

Comment: I have a native compiler. below is the compiler information.

Comment: `Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/gfortran/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.0/lto-wra

Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-trunk/configure --prefix=/mingw --enable-languag
tran,lto --with-gmp=/home/brad/gfortran/dependencies --disable-werror --
hreads --enable-nls --build=i586-pc-mingw32 --enable-libgomp --enable-sh
isable-win32-registry --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-l
ld=mingw32 --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.0 20130302 (experimental) [trunk revision 196403] (GCC)`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605842/how-to-identify-platform-compiler-from-preprocessor-macros

Comment: @M.S.B. But also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor

Answer (score 4):

This might be [GFortran PR 42954](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42954). Since GFortran started using libcpp instead of running cpp in a separate process, many of these built-in macros are missing.

As a workaround, you can as part of your build process generate a file with these builtin macro definitions which you can then include. E.g. have a make target which runs

```
gcc -E -dM - < /dev/null > builtins.inc
```

Then your sources should depend on builtins.inc in the Makefile, and in the beginning of your source files you

```
#include "builtins.inc"
```