# How to retrieve the type of architecture (linux versus Windows) within my fortran code

Tags: linux, windows, architecture, fortran

How can I retrieve the type of architecture (linux versus Windows) in my fortran code? Is there some sort of intrinsic function or subroutine that gives this information? Then I would like to use a switch like this every time I have a system call:

```
if (trim(adjustl(Arch))=='Linux') then
  resul = system('ls > output.txt')
elseif (trim(adjustl(Arch))=='Windows')
  resul = system('dir > output.txt')
else
  write(*,*) 'architecture not supported'
  stop
endif
```

thanks
A.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635716/gfortran-pre-processor-directives-for-different-operating-systems ?

Answer (score 2):

The Fortran 2003 standard introduced the `GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` intrinsic subroutine.  A simple form of call would be

```
call GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE (NAME, VALUE)
```

which will return the value of the variable called `NAME` in `VALUE`.  The routine has other optional arguments, your favourite reference documentation will explain all.  This rather assumes that you can find an environment variable to tell you what the executing platform is.

If your compiler doesn't yet implement this standard approach it is extremely likely to have a non-standard approach; a routine called `getenv` used to be available on more than one of the Fortran compilers I've used in the recent past.

The 2008 standard introduced a standard function `COMPILER_OPTIONS` which will return a string containing the compilation options used for the program, if, that is, the compiler supports this sort of thing.  This seems to be less widely implemented yet than `GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`, as ever consult your compiler documentation set for details and availability.  If it is available it may also be useful to you.

You may also be interested in the 2008-introduced subroutine `EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE` which is the standard replacement for the widely-implemented but non-standard `system` routine that you use in your snippet.  This is already available in a number of current Fortran compilers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no intrinsic function in Fortran for this. A common workaround is to use conditional compilation (through makefile or compiler supported macros) such as [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/280410). If you really insist on this kind of solution, you might consider making an external function, e.g., in C. However, since your code is *built* for a fixed platform (Windows/Linux, not both), the first solution is preferable.

Comment: I think most Fortran compilers support C macros, e.g. look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Preprocessing-and-conditional-compilation.html#Preprocessing-and-conditional-compilation