# What does # before IF and ENDIF mean

Tags: fortran

I know how to use `IF` and `ENDIF` in Fortran, but in many codes I have from others, there is a `#` sign before the `IF`, what does that mean?

```
!USES:
#if ( defined X )
     use Y
#endif
```

Comment: In addition to the points in the answers, it could be useful to note: relating to preprocessing their placement/use is not subject to the rules of the `if` construct/statement of Fortran.  Which is why you can have a `use` statement done conditionally this way.

Comment: Depending on the Fortran compiler, cpp-like preprocessing is invoked by a command line option -fpp or -cpp or by capitalization of file name suffix .F90 or .F or by a GUI project setting. Without that,  the # directives will be flagged as errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are pre-compiler macros, and not Fortran statements. They do the same as regular `if` statements, only at compile time and with a slightly [different syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If).

Note that pre-processor directives are not part of any Fortran Standard, and that they are not supported by every compiler. Generally, they are identical to C pre-processor directives, but not always.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

## #ifdef and #endif are preprocessor directives.

suppose you had a file:

```
! test.F:
     program A
     x=1
#ifdef NEW
     x=0
#endif
     write(*,*) x
     end
```

if you compile it using a preprocessor:

```
    ifort -DNEW test.F -o a.out
```

you should get x =0

otherwise if you compile without -DNEW like

```
    ifort test.F -o a.out
```

in that case you get x=1. The code inside the ifdef is not compiled. [Here are compile time options for gfortran.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Preprocessing-Options.html). A useful situation for [example is this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635716/gfortran-pre-processor-directives-for-different-operating-systems).

Comment: Thank you, these are useful.